# Build Lucene on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, lucene

Has anyone successfully built Lucene in Eclipse? I am trying to build Lucene3.6 and got some yellow error in Eclipse, then i can run demo, but i cannot run Junit tests. Anyone can help me out? I am entirely new to both Lucene and Eclipse..thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved this by myself. Basically need to link test frame work in Lucene 3.6